# Is there something like the GNU locate command in PowerShell?

Tags: windows-8, powershell

Is there an equivalent of the GNU [`locate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) command in Windows 7/8?

`locate` can take as input a file name and gives as output all the paths where files named similarly to input are, e.g.:

```
locate file-with-long-name.txt
/var/www/file-with-long-name.txt
```

Comment: For those of us that don't know `locate`, can you describe what you want it to do?

Comment: @JayBazuzi I did even if it was admittently less than clear, edited to clarify and added sample output

Comment: What does "similar" mean?

Comment: You didn't say, but I'm assuming you mean GNU locate. I'll modify your question.

Comment: @JayBazuzi e.g. searching for index.htm also finds index.html

Comment: Besides where.exe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix-type "locate" on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/327109/unix-type-locate-on-windows)

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous. It is not clear if PowerShell and/or CLI (command-line interface) is mandatory. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/836718/245595) to a *possible duplicate*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not a Windows cmd or PowerShell **builtin** equivalent to Linux/GNU's `locate` command. However, functional equivalents include cmd.exe's `dir /s` as described by `JKarthik`, and these PowerShell options:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Recurse . file-with-long-name.txt
```

Note the use of `.`, telling PowerShell where to begin the search from. You can, of course, shorten when typing at the command line:

```
PS> gci -r . file-with-long-name.txt
```

I do this a lot, so I added a function to my profile:

```
PS> function gcir { Get-ChildItem -Recurse . @args }
PS> gcir file-with-long-name.txt
```

This allows wildcards, similar to `locate`:

```
PS> gcir [a-z]ooo*.txt
```

See `help about_Wildcards` for more details. That can also be written with `Where-Object` like this:

```
PS> gcir | where { $_ -like "[a-z]ooo*.txt"}
```

`locate` has an option to match with regexes. So does PowerShell:

```
PS> gcir | where { $_ -match "A.*B" }
```

PowerShell supports full .NET Regular Expressions. See `about_Regular_Expressions`.

You can do other types of queries, too:

```
PS> gcir | where { $_.Length -gt 50M }  # find files over 50MB in size
```

Performance of these approaches is slow for large collections of files, as it just searches the filesystem. GNU `locate` uses a **database**. Windows now has a searchable database, called **Windows Desktop Search**. There is an API to WDS, which someone has wrapped with a PowerShell cmdlet, here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14602/Windows-Desktop-Search-Powershell-Cmdlet, allowing things like:

```
PS> get-wds “kind:pics datetaken:this month cameramake:pentax”
```

with much better performance than `Get-ChildItem`, and this kind of rich query (and awkward syntax). Also, note that curly quotes work fine in PowerShell, so no need to edit that sample when copy/pasting it.

Maybe someone will find (or write) PowerShell cmdlets that allow idiomatic queries to WDS.

Answer (score 3):

For a PowerShell solution, try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "file-with-long-name.txt" -Recurse
```

This returns all files that match the given name in the current directory and its subdirectories.

The `-Filter` parameter accepts wildcards. If the current directory contains system files that you don't have access to, add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress errors.

For more information, see [`Get-Help Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx).

Comment: At the command prompt, I abbreviate `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `-ea 0`, for ease of typing.

Comment: This answer is better prepended with a warning about the huge difference between `locate` (which looks into a previously generated database, with the pro of speed and the con of not being instantaneously up-to-date) and `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command on windows shell:

```
dir [filename] /s
```

Where filename is the name of the file you're looking for, and `/s` refers to include sub-directories in the search.

**Update** The following command with `/B` shows only bare format, exactly as required. And this seems to be a tad faster.

Do try:

```
 dir [filename] /s /B
```

Source: [Windows 8 Command Line List and Reference](http://commandwindows.com/windows-8-commands.htm)

Comment: this is *scarily slow* compared to linux, but it does eventually find the file. Will mark it as answer if nobody else finds a faster alternative

Comment: Hey, /B displays in bare format (only the location of the file) and this seems to be tad faster. Do check.

Comment: The difference is that `locale` looks in a database (generate/updated by `updatedb`) and `dir` actually searches the full hard disk.

Comment: `dir/s` is slow because it brute-forces the search (looks *everywhere*). It harks back to DOS (being a DOS command), which is why it operates that way. I suspect the only reason it still exists is as a fall-back in case your index database isn't adequate.

Comment: This answer is better prepended with a warning about the huge difference between `locate` (which looks into a previously generated database, with the pro of speed, and the con of not being instantaneously up-to-date) and `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cygwin to mimic the linux toolset or install the MinGW port and you'll have access to a shell with almost all the familiarity of a native linux system

Answer (score -2):

If you are not used to UNIX  *locate*  you don't know what you are missing.

*locate* returns **filenames** **only** from every drive in your PC **instantly**.

Type in:

***locate** some filename*

and every name specified will show up **instantly**. It will NOT look inside your files for fragments.
The speed comes from a database initiated with *updatedb* which can take time, and is normally a daily cron-job.

I could not find anything useful in this thread so I added my solution:
Install Cygwin64, open a terminal, *updatedb* then *locate*

I did a test to highlight performance differences, I did a search of **putty.exe**

On Win10 it took 12 min 50 sec in Explorer, and 4 seconds in Cygwin terminal.

I was not interested in fragments, which was a "bonus" on Explorer search which makes it take more time. Yes, indexing is turned on.

Comment: I believe this shows the usefulness of UNIX locate, it doesn't answer the question very well.

Comment: Right, I gave up on any MS-Windows answers, as most MS-Windows experts are not familiar with this search utility.  Cygwin is a Windows program, albeit clunky for just this function. 
Windows search is badly broken, as can be seen from the above search time. Don't get me started on the Win10 GUI.

Comment: `updatedb` has been very fast for me compared to the time it takes for a trivial search in Windows Explorer. Windows has pathetic indexing performance. Windows is pathetic.