# Windows alternative to locate on ubuntu

Tags: windows, file-search, locate

The locate command on ubuntu is so great that I miss it a lot on Windows 7.

Do you know of an alternative?

Ok I found this but it's not great:

[Is there something like the GNU locate command in PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/502147/is-there-something-like-the-gnu-locate-command-in-powershell)

Thank you

Comment: Explicitly for command-line or a search-tool in general?

Comment: @Robert command-line prefered but search-tool if nothing else, given that it is fast, intantaneous like as the great 'locate' :)

Comment: why the downvote? From when duplicate question begin to get downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a GUI program, [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is a good alternative.

Comment: I am going to try. They could support a command line version/hook, that would be cool.

Comment: Everything is my suggestion, too. Pretty fast once loaded and synchronized but requires administrator permissions to run.

Comment: @Robert: It makes sense – the USN Journal is only readable by administrators, and all other methods of change monitoring are considerably less efficient.

Comment: Excellent. A command line search version would be cool. I guess it can be done with the SDK.

Comment: *Everything* is limited by User Account Control (UAC)... :-(

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command `where` e.g.

`where xcopy`

`c:\windows\System32\xcopy.exe`

Comment: woaw seems to works great and fast, do you know if it uses a kind of database to be fast?

Comment: @unludo: No, because it does not do the same as `locate` does. Windows `where` is very close to `which` in Unixes – that is, it only looks for programs in a few directories preset in `%PATH%`.